# How to remove a registry entry from Windows 2008/Vista

Tags: windows-vista, vbscript, windows-server-2008

I have this script to run on Windows 2008/Vista to remove one registry key, but I can't get it to run:

```
Const HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT     = &H80000000
strComputer = "."
strKeyPath = "Installer\Products\334A4D1453680B74CA87BEE6B7E40113" 
Set objRegistry = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & _
    strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv") 
DeleteSubkeys HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, strKeypath 

Private Sub DeleteSubkeys(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, strKeyPath) 
  strComputer = "."
  Set objRegistry = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & _
    strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv") 

  objRegistry.EnumKey HKEY_CURRENT_USER, strKeyPath, arrSubkeys 
  If IsArray(arrSubkeys) Then 
    For Each strSubkey In arrSubkeys 
        DeleteSubkeys HKEY_CURRENT_USER, strKeyPath & "\" & strSubkey 
    Next 
  End If 

  objRegistry.DeleteKey HKEY_CURRENT_USER, strKeyPath 
End Sub
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

Are you running this as an admin user?  Despite your use of HKEY_CURRENT_USER as a param name, you're trying to delete from HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, which would normally require elevated access.